# Replacement for FirebaseVisonImageMetadata for standalone ML Kit SDKs

Tags: image, firebase-mlkit, google-mlkit

I have been migrating to the new standalone ML Kit from the Firebase ML Kit.

While creating the `FirebaseVisionImage` I used to pass the rotation as `FirebaseVisionImageMetadata.ROTATION_180`, but according to [documentation](https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/migration/android#new), the `FirebaseVisionImageMetadata` class has been removed.

How to set the rotation value while using new SDK classes?

Old code:

```
 mFaceDetector.detectInImage(FirebaseVisionImage.fromMediaImage(
       finalImage, 
       FirebaseVisionImageMetadata.ROTATION_180))
            .addOnSuccessListener(faces -> {
                 // Some logic
             });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was solved by just passing the rotation values in degrees as `int`.

Since the new SDK requires `InputImage` instead of `FirebaseVisionImage`, its `fromMediaImage` method implementation gives the idea. Here is the function:

```
@NonNull
@RequiresApi(19)
public static InputImage fromMediaImage(@NonNull Image var0, int var1) {
    long var2 = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
    Preconditions.checkNotNull(var0, "Please provide a valid image");
    Preconditions.checkArgument(var1 == 0 || var1 == 90 || var1 == 180 || var1 == 270, "Invalid rotation. Only 0, 90, 180, 270 are supported currently.");

    // ...other logic
}
```

This gives the idea that the new function wants the second parameter as `0`, `90`, `180` or `270` as `int` values.

Therefore, we can pass rotation as:

```
mFaceDetector.process(InputImage.fromMediaImage(finalImage, 180)).addOnSuccessListener(faces -> {
     // Some logic
});
```